# React onDrop is not firing

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Below is the sample code which I'm trying to use, which is react + TypeScript.
onDragEnter and onDragOver are working properly but not the **onDrop** event.

```
import * as React from 'react';

export class FileZone extends React.Component {

  onDragOver = (e) => {
    let event = e as Event;
    event.stopPropagation();
  }

  onDragEnter = (e) => {
    let event = e as Event;
    event.stopPropagation();
  }

  onFileDrop = (e) => {
    let event = e as Event;
    event.stopPropagation();

    console.log("onFileDrop");
    alert("dropped")
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        onDragEnter={this.onDragEnter}
        onDragOver={this.onDragOver}
        onDrop={this.onFileDrop}>
        Drag and drop file here
      </div>)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 131, accepted):

You must `preventDefault()` behavior of the **`dragover`** event like this:

```
onDragOver = (e) => {
    let event = e as Event;
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

Preventing default behavior in the `dragover` event "indicates that element is a draggable location", as seen in MDN docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API/Drag_operations#specifying_drop_targets),  [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API/File_drag_and_drop) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/drop). Then the `drop` event will work.

Comment: Had the same issue, this fixed the problem. I don't know, but this looks like a bug in react. With native events there's no need to do such things.

Comment: It's not a bug in React, it's the way the drag and drop events work. The default action for [dragOver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/dragover) is "Reset the current drag operation to none". 
So unless you cancel it the drop doesn't work. Check out [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/drop) for a bit more info. Their example includes this exact point.

Comment: Strange behavior. This fixed my issue as well. Thx!

Answer (score 27):

Simply prevent default ondragover event then it works.

```
onDragOver = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

---

```
return (<div onDragOver={this.onDragOver} {...others}>{children}</div>);
```

Answer (score 5):

There is a problem in your code you have to assign event to `div`

```
render() {
    return (
      <div //you have to remove additional > from here
        onDragEnter={this.onDragEnter}
        onDragOver={this.onDragOver}
        onDrop={this.onFileDrop}>
        Drag and drop file here
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
window.ondragover = function(e) { e.preventDefault(); return false };
window.ondrop = function(e) { e.preventDefault(); return false };
```

Comment: This is not how to do this in React.

Answer (score 2):

The browsers prevent the "drop" actions by default, so you need to prevent them doing that! event.preventDefault() will handle it as you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

```
onDrop={files => this.onFileDrop}>
```

This, should become this:

```
onDrop={this.onFileDrop}>
```

And as you are using 'this." to call the function you will need it to be in the constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.onFileDrop = this.onFileDrop.bind(this);
  }
```

Function:

```
onFileDrop(event) { 
 event.preventDefault(); 
 console.log("qwerty")
}
```

Comment: Updated the above code with the same, but no luck, by the way I'm using typescript

Comment: What do you have in your onFileDrop function? Do you have   `onFileDrop(event)  { event.preventDefault(); console.log("qwerty")}` ?

Answer (score -1):

You need to call the function to fire it up (use the parenthesis):

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        onDragEnter={this.onDragEnter}
        onDragOver={() => { return false }}
        onDrop={files => this.onFileDrop()}> // you were missing the "()"
        Drag and drop file here
      </div>)
  }
```

Comment: In react, if you open and close parenthesis after the function name it will be called many more times than you are expecting. Instead, you should pass a reference to it and to do that  you write it without the parentheses.